# select most recent rows from one table 1 and join to get rows from table 2

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need N number of recent data selecting some columns from table 1 and some from table 2.

For example, I need 2 most recent rows from table 1 and table 2.

Table 1

```
id | Fname  | LName

------------------------

1  | F1     | L1

2  | F2     | L2

3  | F3     | L3

4  | F4     | L4
```

Table 2

```
id | City   | Date

---+----------------------

1  | C1     | 02/23/2014

2  | C2     | 02/01/2014

3  | C3     | 02/20/2014

4  | C4     | 02/19/2014
```

Desired Result

```
Fname| City  | Date

----------------------------

F1   | C1    | 02/23/2014

F3   | C3    | 02/20/2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have the same IDs in both T1 and T2 (why two different tables?).
If so:

```
SELECT FNAME, CITY, MY_DATE
FROM (SELECT T1.FNAME, T2.CITY, T2.MY_DATE
      FROM T2, T1
      WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
      ORDER BY T2.MY_DATE DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 2;
```

Otherwise, please explain what's the difference between T1 and T2...

Comment: Thank you. I have some other columns in both tables T1 and T2. For every row (ID) in T1, you may have multiple rows in T2.